# Facebook Like/Send buttons inconsistent across site pages

Tags: c#, facebook-like, facebook-c#-sdk

I have implemented the Facebook Like and Send button plugin. Look I think its fair to say that this should be fairly straightforward and having stepped though the process I was very happy that this was the case.

I am having an issue now that is causing me some difficulty resolving.

The issue is around an inconsistent display and functionality of the plugin. It works perfectly for some of our site pages and doesnt work at all for others.

**On the pages where the plugin does not work the Send Button doesnt appear and when the Like Button is clicked it opens the Like Dialog very briefly and immediately closes it without any Like Action being recorded**

I have checked all of the site pages through the Facebook Debugger tool and all the pages are being scraped correctly with correct Open Graph Meta Tags etc...

At this stage I am wondering if anybody has had this issue? I am aware that there were issues with the Send Button this year but my understanding was that these issues had been resolved...

website url that displays **incorrectly** is: http://www.todaysdeals.ie/Deal.aspx?dlid=441

website url that displays **correctly** is: http://www.todaysdeals.ie/Deal.aspx?dlid=439

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the problem is in how you're declaring the button code. You've specified a width of 90px in the FBXML code, but Facebook seems to be ignoring this and rendering its code at 150px.

My guess is on the incorrect page, you've got a large number of likes on this page, and it's wrapping the buttons into a hidden area of the div.

I'd start by increasing the width in your FBXML code to at least 176px and see what happens.